# Publishing delay due to Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master

Tags: sitecore-client, logging

I was wondering why my single item publish took over 4 minutes. I checked the logs and found that some job started in the queue in middle of the publish. Below is the reported log,

```
ManagedPoolThread #1 20:43:49 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #1 20:43:49 INFO  Examining schedules (count:1)
ManagedPoolThread #1 20:43:49 INFO  Not due: 16BF09D183124CAD9179F7DF58D29C58-start
9652 20:43:50 ERROR Application error.
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: virtualPath
Source: System.Web
```

Thanks!!

Comment: do you have any custom item:saved handler?

Comment: Nope, there are no any handlers.

Comment: Those logs dont show which process is actually starting. After examining schedules (count: 1) there should be another line like: Starting: Some Task Name (asynchronously). If a similar line follows soon after in the logs, then I suggest searching further to see if the same task always has that exception near it.